# How to read data from excel sheet in python?

Tags: python, selenium, read-data

Is there any python script to read data from excel sheet in selenium python framework?

I have written below code but i don't think its completely right

def getcell(rows,cols):

```
table=list()
record=list()

for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols):
        record.append(SheetName.cell(x,y).value)    
        table.append(record)
        record=[]
        rows=rows+1

return table;
```

print(table)

Comment: I don't think that this question is related to Selenium in any way (it my may merely be indirectly related to test automation). Please edit the question and the tags accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Have you try pandas ? It seems like natural in order to treat your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

try [xrld](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). A python module used to read ms excel sheets. Here is a simple example provided in its readme file

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
print "The number of worksheets is", book.nsheets
print "Worksheet name(s):", book.sheet_names()
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols
print "Cell D30 is", sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3)
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    print sh.row(rx)
```

Comment: hi And3r50n 1, it worked. I have one doubt, can we write code where in there is an excel sheet and we have to read multiple rows using tc id's.for ex: I have to read 1 row by passing an argument tc01.

Comment: yes it will. go ahead and embed the module in program . Please accept the answer and up vote it if it solved your problem

Comment: so can you please help me to write read multiple rows using tc id's script.